# regexp in TCL is matching what is not expected

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set modelList [lsearch -nocase -all -regexp -inline $args {(LAP|CAP)?[0-9]{2,5}}]
```

My this line of code is also matching mac address of format `7081.05e7.ba70`, What am I missing. Please help.

Comment: Tell us what strings should pass that regex check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(LAP|CAP)?` is optional in your regex as you placed a `?` at there.

So your regex matches all of the followings:

```
LAP0123
CAP012
012
01234
```

Comment: but it should not match 081.05e7.ba70 , right? But it is matching that too.

Comment: You didn't place any `^` and `$` around your regex. So it matched partially. For full match: `^(LAP|CAP)?[0-9]{2,5}$`